# Getting Image URL's in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, imageurl

I am very new to any form of coding.  I started the learning process by attempting to make a simple crawler with Scrapy.  It kinda works, but for some reason I can't get an image URL to output properly.  It spits out some "data:image/gif;base64..." value instead of the actual link in the src attribute. I've looked for answers but I can't seem to find anything that gives me a definitive answer (Plus I may not fully understand the issue as well).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def parse(self, response):
    for data in response.css("a.styles__link--2pzz4"):
        yield {
            'title': data.css('a::attr(title)').get(),
            'price': data.css('span::text').get(),
            'url': data.css('a::attr(href)').get(),
            'image url': data.css('img::attr(src)').get(),
        }

        next_page = response.css('li span a::attr(href)').get()
        if next_page is not None:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you give us link that you want to scrape?

Sometimes websites have lazy loads and hide normal links in other `img` attributes. For example, `data-original`, `data-src`, etc. Or keep links to images in jsons, stored in script on page.

Answer (score 0):

Your website might be defining the image data as a base64 encoded blob using a data URI. Basically, the image data is embedded in the HTML, so there is no normal URL available.
Read more here: https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/